# How to sync 2x AWS RDS instances

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have 2x RDS single instances (MySQL) in the same region.

The goal is to copy (A) RDS to (B) RDS on nightly basis.

Is there any way to have this configuration auto sync between 2 RDS instances?

Comment: What do you mean by "copy"? What do you mean by "auto sync" -- is this in one direction, or both directions? Do you want the target database to be totally identical to the source database, or do you want the source data _added_ to the target database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to copy the contents of one Amazon RDS database such that another RDS database contains *identical* content, then it is easiest to **use a snapshot:**

- Create an Amazon RDS Snapshot of the source database
- Launch a new Amazon RDS database instance from the Snapshot
- Delete the previous Amazon RDS database 'B' database, since it is now out-of-date

The new database launched from the Snapshot will be identical to the source database (except for the instance DNS name).

This operation can be done via AWS CLI commands.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into DMS ongoing replication as it seems like a potential solution for your use case https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_BestPractices.html#CHAP_BestPractices.OnGoingReplication

Answer (score 1):

There are three approaches here.

One is that if you want to "refresh" the database schema on nightly basis, you can use logical backup by using `mysqldump/mydumper` to `export/import` the schema and put the script in the scheduler (eg. cron).

The second one you can use is snapshot backup that is provided by AWS, but you need to destroy the previous RDS instances, otherwise you will have many restored RDS from daily snapshot. Ideally, you can create some script that call AWS CLI to remove the previous RDS and restore the snapshot from daily backup. Put the script in the scheduler as well as first option.

A third option is that you can create synchronization using Amazon DMS (Data Migration Service) to migrate the data in a real-time fashion.